# Access remotely to multiply MAMP hosts

Tags: mamp-pro

I have several websites being developed on my home server using MAMP PRO. But I can only access the first host (named 'localhost') from within LAN: `server_ip:8888` brings me there.

What should I do to have access to all other hosts as well?

I guess it should be resolved by ports, but how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself by tries and errors.

1. MAMP settings: set Port Number for your host to different than global (8888 by default)
2. MAMP: FIle->Edit Template -> Apache -> httpd.conf and put there following:

   ```
   Listen XXXX
   <VirtualHost YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:XXXX>
       ServerName <whatever_you_like>
       DocumentRoot "/path/to/your/site/root"
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

where:
`XXXX` is your PORT NUMBER
`YYYY.YYYY.YYYY.YYYY` is your server IP (internal)
Save, restart servers.

After this done I can4 access my 'mail' host by '192.168.0.3:8888' and 'another' by 192.168.0.3:1111. It also lets you access those hosts from anywhere (additional router setup required tho).